# Two table with two headings on HTML how?

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I have this code written but I want to have two tables but with heading.
So the first one where the heading is named Test is displayed over the first table but the second heading Test is not over the second table rather on the first table. So my question is how can I put the second heading over the second table?

```css
body {
  padding: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  table-layout: auto;
}

.fixed {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><a>Test</a></li>
</ul>

<table id="t">
  <thead>

    <tr>
      <th>T</th>
      <th>test</th>
      <th>test</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">Test</a></td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">Test</a></td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">Test</a></td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

<ul>
  <li>
    <class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><a>Test</a></li>
</ul>

  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

So what I Expect is to put the second heading to the second table.[image]

Comment: Can you add the screenshot?

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala from the website ?

Comment: yeah. Screenshots of what are you getting and what are you expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second "table" (your example indicates it is a single table with multiple headers), this should work for you. You were missing the data below it to form it properly.

If you are looking for a second table, simply copy and paste from `<table>` to `</table>`.

```css
body {
  padding: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  table-layout: auto;
}

.fixed {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><a>Test</a></li>
</ul>

<table id="t">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>T1</th>
      <th>T2</th>
      <th>T3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">Test</a></td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">Test</a></td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">Test</a></td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>T1</th>
      <th>T2</th>
      <th>T3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">Test</a></td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">Test</a></td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">Test</a></td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </thead>
```

Comment: I forgot to put the second heading.

Comment: you had the second heading at the bottom of your code

Comment: Oh, okey I understood now.